# Is it safe to rely on milliseconds when calculating dates?

Tags: java, api, date

In java you can call the getTime() method on the Date object to represent a date in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. Is this representation universal across other programming language APIs?

For example, if I ask somebody who is using an API from a different programming language to give me current date and time represented in milliseconds, can I safely make the assumption that I would end up with the same date and time if I calculate this value on the server-side using java.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm building a public API over http where I want the client to provide me with a timestamp which I need to process server-side. My question really is whether it's safe to ask for a date representation in the form of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT, rather than a full string representation such as yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z

Answer (score 6):

No, the millisecond time stamp is far from universal.  I suggest you use a standard string format such as [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) for exchanging time between computers or language runtimes on the same computer.  See also [Wikipedia: System Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the RFC

Answer (score 2):

You cannot in general assume that every numeric timestamps uses January 1, 1970 as the baseline.  But it doesn't really matter, because you *could* specify your API as *requiring* timestamps in that form.  It is a trivial matter to adjust the baseline and / or scale a numeric timestamp to the form you require.

So looking at the alternatives:

- Numeric timestamps take marginally less space in messages, and are marginally easier and cheaper to convert.  However, there is a risk of someone mis-implementing your specification by using the wrong scaling and/or baseline.
- A standard (e.g. ISO) textual format uses (marginally) more space and is marginally harder to convert, but standard parser / unparser implementations exist.  (There is still the risk that someone will use a variant that your specification doesn't allow.)
- A non-standard textual format is not a good idea because of potential for mis-implementation and ambiguity in the format.  (For example 3-letter timezones are ambiguous)
- Textual formats are easier for a human to read; e.g. for debugging purposes.

But all in all, I don't think it matters if you use a numeric or (standards-based) textual format, **provided** that you clearly specify the required format, and what it means.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on that date format as Java also only gets that date from the operating system. It does not matter what programming language you use. See [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in Wikipedia for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a straight answer, I'll give a reference to OAuth.
According to [the OAuth 1.0 specification](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#nonce):

> Unless otherwise specified by the Service Provider, the timestamp is
>   expressed in the **number of seconds** since January 1, 1970 00:00:00
>   GMT.

So, if you really don't really need a millisecond granurality, do what others do.